# How to use one model as source for 'choices' in another model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models: User, UserProfile and Programme. User holds the names of all users;

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = model.Charfield(...)
    last_name = model.Charfield(...)
    ...
```

UserProfile contains the attributes associated with each user (e.g. sales manager(sm), program manager(pm), delivery manager(dm) etc.

```
class UserProfile(model.Model):
    user = model.ForeignKey(User, on_delete...)
    sm = model.BooleanField(default = False, editable=True...)
    pm = model.BooleanField(default = False, editable=True...)
    dm = model.BooleanField(default = False, editable=True...)
```

A User may have any combination of UserProfile attributes. For example:
User-1: sm
User-2: sm, pm
User-3: dm
User-4: sm, dm
...

Every programme in Programme must have a user assigned for each of sm, pm, dm so my challenge is finding a way to generate a 'choices' list for each of sm, pm and dm limited to Users with the appropriate attribute.

```
class Programme(model.Models):
    programme_name = models.Charfield(...)
    AND ESSENTIALLY:
    sm = only users with userprofile.sm = True
    pm = only users with userprofile.pm = True
    dm = only users with userprofile.dm = True
```

I've tried adding a function to UserProfile then referencing it in Programme:

```
UserProfile(model.Models):
....

def get_pm(self):
    pm_list = []
    pm = UserProfile.objects.filter(pm=True)
    for i in pm:
        pm_list.append(i.user.last_name)
        return pm_list
```

and in Programme:

```
Programme(model.Models):
    pm = models.Charfield(choices=UserProfile.get_pm, ...
```

but this generates the error: 'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).

Similarly, I've tried adding the same function to Programmes/models.py but this generates the same error.

I know I'm missing the obvious but all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a separate model for User profile:

```
 class User(AbstractUser):
     first_name = model.Charfield(...)
     last_name = model.Charfield(...)
     POST_CHOICES = (
       ('sm', ("sm")),
       ('sm', ("pm")),
       ('sm', ("dm")),
       )
     post=models.CharField(choices=POST_CHOICES,max_length=150, blank=True)
     programme_name = models.Charfield(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

You can filter out the users who are sm,for example using filter queries or you can use model managers for this

Comment: That approach is okay for static choices. My challenge is that the number of Users and UserProfiles will change frequently, so choices must change frequently as well. In fact, for Programmes on the same date it will be necessary to filter out User/UserProfiles already committed to a Programme/Date pair.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a ridiculous amount of reading, trial and error, a simple solution emerges: Simple override the form fields using an appropriate query -

```
class ProgrammeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Programme
    fields = [
        'name', 'company', 'status', 'pm', 'sm', 'dm', 'idm','start_date', 'end_date', 'delivery_type'
    ]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProgrammeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    sm_choices = UserProfile.objects.filter(sm=True)
    pm_choices = UserProfile.objects.filter(pm=True)
    dm_choices = UserProfile.objects.filter(dm=True)
    idm_choices = UserProfile.objects.filter(idm=True)
    self.fields['sm'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=sm_choices)
    self.fields['pm'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=pm_choices)
    self.fields['dm'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=dm_choices)
    self.fields['idm'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=idm_choices)
```